# Modal Presentation when using Xamarin-sidebar

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a modal view I present before a few pages in my application that we use to display a full screen sponsor image.

In my `ViewModel` I have it load some images and then delay before calling `Close(this)`. This works fine for any page that is marked as `ResetRoot` for the sidebar. But any page that is part of the stack will just dismiss the the page that created the modal instead of the modal itself.

```
public async override void ViewAppeared()
{
    base.ViewAppeared();

    if (_sponsors.Count() > 1)
    {
        foreach (var sponsor in _sponsors)
        {
            Image = sponsor.Image;
            await Task.Delay((AppSettings.DefaultSponsorDisplayTimeInSeconds * 1000) / _sponsors.Count());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Image = _sponsors.First().Image;
        await Task.Delay((AppSettings.DefaultSponsorDisplayTimeInSeconds * 1000));
    }

    await NavigationService.Close(this);
}
```

Update: Working now. I had to override the Close method in my custom presenter.

```
public override void Close(IMvxViewModel toClose)
{
    var hasModal = ModalViewControllers.Any();

    if (hasModal)
        CloseModalViewController(toClose);
    else
        base.Close(toClose);
}
```

Just checks to see if there are any modal views loaded on the current stack and manually calls CloseModalViewController to close the modal version it just closing the last item on the navigation stack.